# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ convergent?
The required condition is ok, but how to find a minorant or majorant series for this.

Comment: Use $\dfrac{2}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small $x>0$, $0\leqslant \tan x\sim x$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the limit comparison test with $a_n = \frac{1}{n} \tan(\frac{1}{n})$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\tan(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}$.  Now just apply L'Hopitals'rule to get that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$> 0.  Hence, by the limit comparison test, since $\sum b_n$ converges, so does $\sum a_n$.